# AngularJS - Directive inside ng-switch not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive inside `ng-switch` as follows:

```
<div ng-switch on="myModel">
    <div ng-switch-when="foo">
        <zippy></zippy>
    </div>
    //Other ng-switch-when directives
</div>
```

The directive is defined as:

```
app.directive('zippy', function() {
    return {
        scope: false,
        template: "Hello FooBar"
    };
});
```

Now, when the page loads, although `myModel` does become to `foo`, the template does not load. Following is the state of the element in the borwser:

```
<div ng-switch-when="foo" class="ng-scope">
    <zippy></zippy>
</div>
```

The class `ng-scope` gets appended - thats it. The element does not change - the directive is not replaced with the template. What am I doing wrong? How can I get the directives to work?

Comment: By default, directives are "attribute only", so at least you need to add `restrict: 'E'` to your directive definition.

Comment: My bad! I knew that there is a default value for `restrict` but I was assuming that it is element and not attribute.

Comment: i am having the exact same problem but i have 'EA' for the restrict property. The ng-scope class gets applied to my custom directive element but it does not get rendered. Appears to be a bug in angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the `restrict` to your directive:

Demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/Jc77jrY4U0xGalN5QkZA

```
app.directive('zippy', function() {
    return {
        scope: false,
        template: "Hello FooBar",
        restrict: 'E'
    };
});
```

Documentation:  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

restrict - String of subset of EACM which restricts the directive to a specific directive declaration style. If omitted directives are allowed on attributes only.

E - Element name:

A - Attribute:

C - Class:

M - Comment: